# Is Initializing a constant lvalue reference from an rvalue undefined?

Tags: c++, reference, temporary-objects

I have this example:

```
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;

  struct Foo
  {
      int const& rci; 
      Foo(int const& x) : rci(x){}
  };

  int main()
  {
      Foo f(7);
      cout << f.rci << endl;
  
  }
```

I've tried this code on many compilers and it works fine printing `7` because the reference member is bound to a temporary but running it on the application decoder it gives me value `0` rather than `7`.

Is this a problem in the application Decoder or in my code?

Comment: Probably works with an integer literal because the compiler may place the literal into effectively a static variable. For all intents and purposes, though, you've got a dangling reference.

Comment: compiling with `g++ -O -Wall` (or O1/O2/...) produces `warning: ‘<anonymous>’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]` and prints 0. Without optimization no warning and prints 7. The problem is not *Decoder* but your source code

Comment: @AndyG You are correct.

Comment: The life of the `7` ends right after `Foo f(7);`. Then `f.rci` becomes a dangling reference. Try with ASAN ([`-fsanitize=address`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bKbz6o)): `ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope`